# JQuery: Iterating through table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I want to iterate through all rows one by one by which i can get specific columns value but one by one.Click on row is triggered. I want to do something like this. thanks in advance.

```
  var t=0;
  $(document).delegate('tr', "click", function (e) {
        $(this).children().each(function () {   
           // alert("child" + $(this).text());
            alert("latvalue" + $('tr td.val1')[t].text());
           alert("latvalue" + $('tr td.val2')[t].text());
t++;
        })
```

table:

```
 <tr ><td id="1">item.Date</td><td class="val1">value</td><td  class="val2">value</td><td  class="val3">value</td></tr>
```

Comment: which version of `jquery` you are using? and what's the problem here? Your question is quite unclear..

Comment: share your markup also... what is `t`?

Comment: `$('tr td.val1')[t].text()` will give you an error

Comment: i am doing it in visual studio 2010 and working in .net ... i am new to asp.net so don't know how to find jquery version

Comment: ok ok its jquery 1.8.11

Comment: t is var which is intitially 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alert the value of the `val1` and `val2` element in the clicked row then

```js
$(document).delegate('tr', "click", function(e) {
  alert("latvalue: " + $('td.val1 ', this).text());
  alert("latvalue: " + $('td.val2 ', this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="val1">1.1</td>
    <td class="val2">1.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="val1">2.1</td>
    <td class="val2">2.2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="val1">3.1</td>
    <td class="val2">3.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over all row of table

```
$(document).delegate('tr', "click", function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function () {  
            alert('latValue' + $(this).find('.val1').text());
            alert('latValue' + $(this).find('.val2').text());
            alert('latValue' + $(this).find('.val3').text());
        });
```